# Matching moments of fitted parametric distribution in Python is inaccurate

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution, data-fitting

In the following code, I generate a random variable `x` which I know is Normally distributed, so I fit a parametric Normal distribution to it (through maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters) in order to simulate a synthetic variable called `y` that should match the properties of the original data. The statistical moments (mean, standard deviation) of `x` and `y` should match too.

Why then don't the moments of `y`'s distribution, match that of `x`'s distribution?  In one run of the code below, the mean of `y` (0.052) could be 5 times as large as `x`'s (0.01), sometimes even negative when it should be positive

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

n = 2000
x = norm.rvs(size=n)
y = norm(*norm.fit(x)).rvs(size=n)

for i in [x,y]:
    print("mu={:.4f}, sd={:.4f}".format(np.mean(i), np.std(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why then don't the moments of y's distribution, match that of x's
> distribution?

***They do - or at least they do within the expected error*** <sup>(1)</sup>

A quick observation is they are both close to the standard normal distribution; their first moments are both close to 0 and their second moment close to 1. However, notice that x is sampled from `N(0,1)` and y is sampled from `N(mean(x), std(x))`.

### Large sample size n

If you want their values to be closer than simply increase the sample size `n`. We'll fix the `random_state` for reproducibility <sup>2</sup>

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

n = 200000

for i in range(5):
    x = norm.rvs(size=n, random_state=i)
    y = norm(*norm.fit(x)).rvs(size=n, random_state=i)

    print("Trial {}".format(i))
    for i in [x, y]:
        print("mu={:.4f}, sd={:.4f}".format(np.mean(i), np.std(i)))
```

This yields:

```
Trial 0
mu=0.0033, sd=0.9980
mu=0.0067, sd=0.9960
Trial 1
mu=0.0045, sd=0.9977
mu=0.0089, sd=0.9953
Trial 2
mu=-0.0004, sd=0.9981
mu=-0.0008, sd=0.9963
Trial 3
mu=-0.0019, sd=0.9965
mu=-0.0037, sd=0.9930
Trial 4
mu=-0.0052, sd=0.9992
mu=-0.0104, sd=0.9984
```

### Small sample size n

On small sample size `n`, we'd naturally expect some discrepancy between `x` and `y` because we are actually drawing another sample from `y`. However, the we can observe how the fitted parameters behave as expected like so:

```
n = 200
for i in range(5):
    x = norm.rvs(size=n, random_state=i)    
    print("Trial {}".format(i))
    print(np.mean(x), np.std(x), norm(*norm.fit(x)).args)
```

This yields

```
Trial 0
0.07091049314116117 1.0214227686959954 (0.07091049314116117, 1.0214227686959954)
Trial 1
0.1066888148479486 0.9100459829739235 (0.1066888148479486, 0.9100459829739235)
Trial 2
0.012250008696874187 1.0800421002497833 (0.012250008696874187, 1.0800421002497833)
Trial 3
-0.07079063505988327 0.9767123391405987 (-0.07079063505988327, 0.9767123391405987)
Trial 4
0.028540839305884236 0.9537561748836348 (0.028540839305884236, 0.9537561748836348)
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Have not actually calculated the standard error so correct me if I'm wrong. A quick search at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33547/how-does-the-standard-error-work) gives a nice explanation about [Standard Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) in general.

<sup>(2)</sup> Fixing the random state `x` and `norm(*norm.fit(x))` does not imply random samples from the later should produce `N(mean(x), std(x))`. Then again, refering to <sup>(1)</sup> above Why should it?.

Comment: how, in my original code, can I enact the 2nd approach of fixing the `random_state`? Is it more accurate than the 1st approach of increasing sample size depicted in your answer? In my application, small sample sizes of `n=50` are the norm

Comment: yup, I have just realized I'm wrong on my claim regarding the random state!

Comment: yup what? are you  retracting the `random_state` approach?

Comment: any comments regarding the small sample setting when trying to match moments with a parametric distribution

Comment: Sure, updated the first item in the footnote. Notice the second half of the my answer shows the fitted parameters are exactly `mean(x)` and `std(x)`. So this is really a question of: "Given `N(a, b)`, how large should N be to for the sample mean and std to be sufficiently close to `a` and `b`".

I'll be deleting my comment on `random state` since it has already been address in the question now - and also because it is badly worded and might be misleading.

Comment: @develarist added a link to the relevant stats.stackexchange question. Here is the same link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33547/how-does-the-standard-error-work

Comment: what good is fitting parametric distributions to real data then, if the parametric model is a bad copy of the real data? If we can't even get the moments right, the model could be worse than using the real data

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bad copy" here, the model performs MLE as expected... or are you asking WHY we use parametric models in general?.

Comment: if the parametric distribution doesn't replicate the properties of the real data, then it is considered a bad copy of the data. There could in fact be no set of MLE-optimal parameters that properly replicate the original data's intrinsic properties

Comment: The whole idea of parameter fitting presupposes the "real" data that we have is actually just a "sample" of a larger population - which in our case we presume to follow the normal distribution `N(mean(X), std(X))`. In other words, we presume the data we have is NOT a complete representation of the general population (i.e. it's just a sample). If you want the MLE to have `N(0,1)` then ofcourse that's very unlikely because a sample is not perfect, hence the Standard Error I linked to the answer (I highly suggest to open that link). Edit; typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225636/discussion-between-leonardus-chen-and-develarist).